# Extend NativeScript control - SetNativeView

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

I want to extend the NativeScript Switch UI component and use it as a custom directive.

```
@Directive({
    selector: "CustomSwitch"
})
export class CustomSwitch extends Switch {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // Add custom events here
        if (isIOS) {
            // Change background and other properties here.
        }
    }
}
```

I can see that the ViewBase class a method like setNativeView. Could anybody share an example of how this could be achieved and what might be the better way to do it.

CSS can help with global styling but I also need the ability to extend the component to expose custom events.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up NativeScript component vs Angular features, if you need a directive, you don't have to extend `Switch` or any {N} component.

Just apply the selector and inject the `ElementRef` into your constructor which would be pointing to the `Switch` (or whichever element you have applied selector on), you could simply change the background color of it. Just same as how you would do it in Angular Web apps.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "CustomSwitch"
})
export class CustomSwitchDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const switch = <Switch>this.el.nativeElement;
    switch.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}
```

Comment: The application is created in Angular and I am indeed trying to extend the compoenent using the Angular 'directives'. If I do what you suggest, I will have to do it everywhere I use the component. I should be able to create a directive with the modifications and just use it as is everywhere in my application.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to apply this directive without modifying your HTML for Switch tag all over your application? If yes, it's still simple, you just have to use the tag name for your directive, so it gets applied to all switches by default.